# iPhone Cannot debug any new projects on my iPhone

Tags: iphone

When I click my iPhone into the USB port, I hear the clicking sound and on my project it shows checking dd symbols and a little progress bar appears. But, when I click on the drop down list, upper right hand corner, my device does not show up, still says any iOS device.  When I click debug, a box comes up saying xcode cannot run using using the selected device.
"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination"

I checked to see what sdk version my project was using, it is 5.1.
On the organizer it says my iPhone is using software version 5.0.1.1,

Questions,
Do I have to upgrade my iPhone to 5.1?
I went to iTunes to upgrade it and they only had a option for 5.1.1, if I upgrade it to 5.1.1, will it still work with my xcode which has sdk 5.1 not 5.1.1

Any idea how to get my iPhone to work with the new projects created?
Also, the old projects are using sdk 5.1 and they run fine, could it be a different problem?

Comment: please consider proof-reading your question before sending it, fixing spelling mistakes, typos and grammar.  It was difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the "Deployment Target" for targets and project to your device version.

To do this, click the project in the navigator -> info for project and summary for targets. There you find the deployment target.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try run a any XCode 3. And open him Organizer. Then will show a question about Collecting device. Press and reconnect a device. Must help. This helps in my case :)